# How can I transform a pointer to the type I input in C++?

Tags: c++, types, casting, clang, memset

I have a question here:

I want to generate a type_t pointer (type_t *), pointing to a memory block, with specified value stored in it.

In another word, its input is:

- string value,
- string type
  and its output is:
- (type*)pointer , pointing to some memory storing 'value'.

I don't know how to do this. I tried to use templates, but I think it need 'type', not the "string type". My only idea is to generate a new cpp file with these information and use it to achieve that. But that's quite awkward when I want to generate enoumous values...

I come up to this question when diving in clang tooling, with QualType and binary value in my hand, and I want to recover the original value. I tried to use the constructors in Expr or VarDecl, but failed to achieve my goal.

Can anyone provide some thoughts? Thanks a lot for your reading this message.

---

Thanks a lot for all your efforts! I think I should get the question clearer with some code

My goal is to write a function like this

```cpp
type_t* func(QualType type_t, string value) 
{ /* some magic here */}
```

or maybe

```cpp
type_t* func(string type_t, string value) 
{ /* some magic here */}
```

It sounds impossible, cause the type is not even determined before the input QualType is determined.

Sure `void*` is a great idea to be used as a middleware, I still wonder how I could write

```cpp
type_t* func(string type_t, void* memory_block) 
{ /* some magic here */}
```

I think the question is the same as: **How can we input a type message and output some value (already existed maybe) with that type?**

Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry don't understand the question. Maybe some examples would help?

Comment: What achitecture are you on? The usual way to get memory for a type is either for local (or possibly global) objects: `type_t t; type_t* ptr = &t;`, if you need dynamically allocated memory `new type_t();` – or, if you need more than one instance: `type_t t[n]; /* local array */ new type_t[n]; /* dynamic array */`. Note that local arrays decay to pointers automatically if need be.

Comment: If you have *direct* access to memory, usually on a bare micro controller, and need a very specific memory address assigned to your object (or if you have created memory in advance – keep an eye on correct alignment then!) you can use placement new: `type_t* t = new (0x20102021) type_t(); type_t* array = new (0x20122010) type_t[n];`.

Comment: @MartinYork I edited my description, maybe it's clearer now?

Comment: @Aconcagua I'm not quite sure how I should describe my 'architecture', I'm trying to do this in with C++ with help of  Clang tooling, on CentOS system.

Comment: @Aconcagua In my opinion, the difficulty is that, the type is input as a string. It's like, with a string storing "int", we want to cast some value to "int" type. We cannot use type stored in string as a type (maybe?)

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks a lot for this idea! This really inspires me. In fact I'm trying to do this just because I want to avoid doing alignment things. Like with a struct type defined in C++ , I want to cast the corresponding value to this type and read out the members in it, but I don't want to do the alignment work manually. On one hand, it can be of enoumous work; On the other hand, the alignment strategy may be different on different compiling strategy(maybe, according to LLVM doc). Thanks a lot for your idea again!

Comment: @DAsp If you read in the data from a string, most likely you will have to parse it anyway. How depends entirely on the format the string is in, e. g. JSON, XML, ... If the string contains *binary* data then you might try [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy)-ing it into the struct. Be aware that this is only safe for pure POD types, anything else most likely breaks. If data comes from a file be aware that this is not fully portable, other platforms might differ in alignment, endianness, data representation and others, though apart from first one not too likely.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks a lot for your suggestions! Finnaly I decide to create a destination file using the input type string. memcpy will help me a lot with this!

Comment: Suppose for a minute you can do what you want. What do you plan to do with the return value? Can you show some pseodocode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of functionality is not provided in c or c++.You can do that in python using exec().
One thing you can do to solve this problem is to declare some of the variables beforehand with the same name as the string that you want to pass.

Answer (score -3):

You can use void pointers to cast any type of pointers. let me know if it works.IT would be great if you provide a script of what you want to do

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my question clear. To use void pointer is surely a good idea as midpart, but it still remains the problem how to cast (void*) to (type_t*), which I think is the main difficulty of the problem. Thanks for your answer though